# Spring Data JPA auto ordering rows based on editable position property

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I'm building a simple ToDo app using Spring Boot in Kotlin. I'm new to both. The following is the data class, I use to persist data via JPA in MySQL database.

```
@Entity @Table
data class Task(
        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column val id: Long,
        @Column var title: String,
        @Column var isCompleted: Boolean
)
```

And this is the JPA Repository.

```
@Repository interface TaskRepository: JpaRepository<Task, Long>
```

User can have a list of tasks.

I have two requirements, First is that when user adds a new task, it has to be added at the end of the list, which means that when I retrieve from the database I need the list in the order it was saved. I thought of achieving this by adding a position property like below, which auto increments. Do suggest if there is a better alternative. Created time based ordering will not suit my other requirements.

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column var position: Int
```

Second requirement is that the user can re-arrange the tasks. So for example, the user can move the task at 8th position to 2nd. To achieve this, I'm thinking of increasing the position of each task from 2 to 7 by one and then change position of the chosen task to 2.

I don't know how to achieve this with a single query. Is that even possible? And is this the right way to do it?

Also if the user deletes a task, ideally I would want to subtract the postion of all tasks by one. But if it's costly, I can live without that.

I really liked the Spring Boot's convention over configuration design, so I hope there must be an easier and better way to achieve my requirements.

Comment: For the second part, you can use a case statement. You're not the first to want to do this.

Comment: @Strawberry I clearly know I'm not the first one to want to do this. That's why I'm asking is there a tried and tested better approach?

Comment: Any news on how to change the position of your task?

Answer (score 0):

Such functionality is part of the JPA spec and can be achieved using the `@OrderColumn` annotation.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html

> Specifies a column that is used to maintain the persistent order of a
>   list. The persistence provider is responsible for maintaining the
>   order upon retrieval and in the database. **The persistence provider is
>   responsible for updating the ordering upon flushing to the database to
>   reflect any insertion, deletion, or reordering affecting the list**.

So you can simply define a `@OneToMany` from User to Task and with this additional annotation the JPA provider will maintain the persistent order column based on your manipulation of the list.